# How to go to a specific page using the button? Flutter

Tags: flutter

I create Welcome Page, when clicking the button I would like the user to be redirected to the home page, but when I click it gives several errors. I don't know how to program very well in flutter, can someone help me?

I tried in many ways, and they all fail. If you have to press the button to restart the APP it would also work, but I don't know how to solve it in any way

WELCOME PAGE (I would like to be redirected to HOME by clicking the button)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../main.dart';
import '../models/items.dart';

import '../helpers/helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';


void main() => runApp(Welcome());
Future<void> Return() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> parentScaffoldKey;
  WelcomeScreen({Key key, this.parentScaffoldKey}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {

  List<Widget> slides = items
      .map((item) => Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Image.asset(
              item['image'],
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: 220.0,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(item['header'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 50.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0XFF3F3D56),
                          height: 2.0)),
                  Text(
                    item['description'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        letterSpacing: 1.2,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        height: 1.3),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )))
      .toList();


  double currentPage = 0.0;
  final _pageViewController = new PageController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: Helper.of(context).onWillPop,
    child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageViewController,
              itemCount: slides.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                _pageViewController.addListener(() {
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage = _pageViewController.page;
                  });
                });
                return slides[index];
              },
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                )
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {

                 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                return HomeWidget();
                  


                },
                highlightElevation: 2,
                splashColor: Color(0xFF2F4565),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                color: Color(0XFFEA5C44),
                child: Text(
                  "Permitir",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
               ),
              )
            ],
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

HOMEPAGE (I would like to be redirected to that page by clicking the button on the WELCOME page)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';
import '../elements/CardsCarouselWidget.dart';
import '../elements/CaregoriesCarouselWidget.dart';
import '../elements/DeliveryAddressBottomSheetWidget.dart';
import '../elements/GridWidget.dart';
import '../elements/ProductsCarouselWidget.dart';
import '../elements/ReviewsListWidget.dart';
import '../elements/SearchBarWidget.dart';
import '../elements/ShoppingCartButtonWidget.dart';
import '../repository/settings_repository.dart' as settingsRepo;
import '../repository/user_repository.dart';


class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> parentScaffoldKey;

  HomeWidget({Key key, this.parentScaffoldKey}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends StateMVC<HomeWidget> {
  HomeController _con;
  @override

  _HomeWidgetState() : super(HomeController()) {
    _con = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.sort, color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
          onPressed: () => widget.parentScaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: settingsRepo.setting,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return Text(
              value.appName ?? S.of(context).home,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new ShoppingCartButtonWidget(iconColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor, labelColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
        ],
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: _con.refreshHome,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: SearchBarWidget(
                  onClickFilter: (event) {
                    widget.parentScaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20, right: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.stars,
                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (currentUser.value.apiToken == null) {
                        _con.requestForCurrentLocation(context);
                      } else {
                        var bottomSheetController = widget.parentScaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                          (context) => DeliveryAddressBottomSheetWidget(scaffoldKey: widget.parentScaffoldKey),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                        );
                        bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
                          _con.refreshHome();
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.my_location,
                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    S.of(context).top_markets,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    S.of(context).near_to + " " + (settingsRepo.deliveryAddress.value?.address ?? S.of(context).unknown),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CardsCarouselWidget(marketsList: _con.topMarkets, heroTag: 'home_top_markets'),
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.trending_up,
                  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  S.of(context).trending_this_week,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  S.of(context).clickOnTheProductToGetMoreDetailsAboutIt,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                ),
              ),
              ProductsCarouselWidget(productsList: _con.trendingProducts, heroTag: 'home_product_carousel'),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.category,
                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    S.of(context).product_categories,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CategoriesCarouselWidget(
                categories: _con.categories,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.trending_up,
                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    S.of(context).most_popular,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: GridWidget(
                  marketsList: _con.popularMarkets,
                  heroTag: 'home_markets',
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.recent_actors,
                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    S.of(context).recent_reviews,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: ReviewsListWidget(reviewsList: _con.recentReviews),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set up the route:

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(), //NOTE: Change the FirstScreen() to your own screen's class name (ex: WelcomeScreen())
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(), //NOTE: Change the SecondScreen() to your own screen's class name (ex: HomeWidget())
    '/third': (context) => ThirdScreen(),
  },
);
```

And then, inside your button, navigate to the page:

```
// Within the `FirstScreen` widget
onPressed: () {
  // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

NOTE: One of your pages must be named as `/` to prevent error, for the full tutorial please visit [this link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#3-navigate-to-the-second-screen)

Comment: I tried, this is showing: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/second", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Comment: Have you change the `SecondScreen()` to `HomeWidget()` (or your home page's class name)?